# How to transform from the spacecraft coordinate system to image coordinates?

Tags: image-processing

Assume e.g. that in the spacecraft coordinate system, I have a target vector

$ \vec{p_\text{t}} = \begin{pmatrix} -11.980\\ -68.051\\ 55.031 \end{pmatrix}\text{km}$,

which is related to the Earth Mean Equator (EME) J2000 reference frame. I also have the spacecraft offset vector relative to EMEJ2000

$ \vec{p_\text{sc}} = \begin{pmatrix} -262041633.729\\ 115960324.885\\ 89603436.304 \end{pmatrix}\text{km}$,

and its rotation quaternion (in the form $[\text{cos}(a/2), n_x \text{sin}(a/2)$, $n_y \text{sin}(a/2), n_z \text{sin}(a/2)]$)

$ q_\text{sc} = \left( 0.86476171, -0.43595577, -0.05902956, 0.24216783 \right)$,

as well as the offset vector of the spacecraft origin relative to the camera

$ \vec{p_\text{cam}} = \begin{pmatrix} -0.001234\\ -0.000157\\ 0.001390 \end{pmatrix}\text{km}$,

and its rotation quaternion (also in the form $[\text{cos}(a/2), n_x \text{sin}(a/2)$, $n_y \text{sin}(a/2), n_z \text{sin}(a/2)]$)

$ q_\text{cam} = \left( 0.99999815, 0.00009373, 0.00027332, 0.00190238 \right)$.

How can I use this information to calculate the position of the target in image (pixel) coordinates?

The camera has a FOV of $2.208° \times 2.208°$, $2048 \times 2048$ pixels, a resolution of $1.882 \cdot 10^{-5}$rad, a focal length of $0.7173\text{m}$, and a pixel size of $13.5 \cdot 10^{-6}\text{m}$.

Comment: You need to know the pixel pitch of your camera: how many arc-seconds per pixel?  Also, check your units.  p_sc is 300 million km, which is the diameter of earth's orbit.  at that distance, the entire earth subtends less than 5 arc-seconds.  even if it were supposed to be 300 thousand km, that's still most of the way to the moon; what satellite is this?  the camera lever arm seems reasonable, but what does the target vector mean?  the normalization is weird (88.334 km), and it's either nearly perpendicular to p_sc (if we draw it from the tip of p_sc), or nearly indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for you feedback! This is data from the Rosetta spacecraft. The target vector points from Rosetta to the center of mass of comet 67P. I would like to know where it is located in an image. Of course you're right about the cameda data. I update the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a [paper](https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/5412929/Visser_-_Vision_based_motion_control_for_a_humanoid_head.pdf) on a similar problem, long time ago. I'll try to provide the gist of it.

You need a model for the camera, so that you can map a point in 3D space to a point in the image. A simple model that is useful for this is the [pinhole camera model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model). This model assumes an image plane at the focal depth of the camera.

In the following I use $p_\text{name}^{\Psi}$ to denote vector $p_\text{name}$ expressed in coordinate frame $\Psi$ and $H_{\Psi_1}^{\Psi_2}$ to denote a [homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) transformation from $\Psi_1$ to $\Psi_2$.

Start with the 3D coordinates of the target and apply a coordinate transformation to a coordinate frame that has its origin in the camera's aperture:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} p_\text{target}^\text{camera} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = H_\text{EME}^\text{camera} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} p_\text{target}^\text{EME} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} .
$$

The transformation matrix $H_\text{EME}^\text{camera}$ can be computes as

$$
H_\text{EME}^\text{camera} = H_\text{sc}^\text{camera} \cdot H_\text{EME}^\text{sc},
$$
with
$$
H_\text{EME}^\text{sc} = \begin{bmatrix}
R_\text{EME}^\text{sc} & p_\text{sc}^\text{EME} \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
H_\text{sc}^\text{camera} = \begin{bmatrix}
R_\text{sc}^\text{camera} & p_\text{camera}^\text{sc} \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$R_\text{EME}^{sc}$ and $R_{sc}^{camera}$ are rotation matrices that follow from your spacecraft and camera quaternions. See [the Wikipedia page on quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix) to see how to convert from quaternions to rotation matrix.

With the target point converted to the appropriate camera coordinate frame, you can project $p_\text{target}^\text{camera} = (x, y, z)^\text{target}_\text{camera}$ onto the image plane as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= \frac{f}{z} x, \\
b &= \frac{f}{z} y,
\end{aligned}
$$

where $x,y,z$ are the coordinates of the target in the camera coordinate frame, $f$ is the focal length of the camera, and $a,b$ are the 2D coordinates of the target in the image plane.

From this, use the pixel size (pitch) to convert to image pixel coordinates.

The focal depth of the camera is typically known. This model does not take into account distortion by the lens, but I assume that the images you are provided with have been corrected already for visual distortions. If you have raw imagery that has not been corrected yet, you need to apply some correction model, which goes beyond this answer and my expertise.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the elaborate answer! One question though: I assume in the last two equations $f$ is the focal depth, but what is $z$? And are $x_\text{camera}$ and $y_\text{camera}$ the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $p^\text{target}_\text{camera}$?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, it would be great if you share a link to your paper anyways.

Comment: @mapf I made some edits to clarify. Is this better?  Also, the paper is available from my university for free nowadays, so I added the link in. It's in robotics, so much of it is not really related; section III-A is the relevant paragraph.

Comment: I'm currenlty trying to implement your solution, however I got stuck at the penultimate step. How can I multiply $H_\text{EME}^\text{camera}$, which is a 4x4 matrix, with $p_\text{target}^\text{EME}$, which is a 1x3 vector?

Comment: @mapf sorry, my bad, that's some notational sloppiness from my side. I fixed it: you need to make $p$ a 4x1 by adding a 1 below it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I got the computation running, but somehow the results are off. I don't doubt your solution though, so I'm not sure what went wrong. Maybe the pinhole camera model is too simple for Rosetta's OSIRIS camera? I used this [`Python Quaternion package`](https://pypi.org/project/Quaternion/) for calculating the rotation matrices. I already checked their computation against the wiki article and it seems sound. They only use a different quaternion format, but I corrected for that. I used `numpy` for the matrix multiplications and tripple checked the data. I got $(a, b) = (-15533, 6803)$.

Comment: @mapf Getting the rotations and vectors correct is always tricky. It's easy to mess up a minus-sign somewhere. I recommend making a 3D visualization of each step of the coordinate transformation to see if it matches your expectations. Start with all coordinate frames aligned (no rotation) and points on the principle axes of each coordinate frame (i.e. $[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]$) and get the translations right. Then start rotating each frame along one axis at the time to get the rotations right. Also recall that the inverse of a rotation is $R^T$, but that the inverse of $H$ is **not** $H^T$.

Comment: I used to have a Python package specifically for this purpose, that would 3D plots coordinate frame unit vectors etc. when I wrote the paper. Lost it long since though, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133090/discussion-between-ludo-and-mapf).

Comment: Ok, so after a long break I had to get back on solving this problem but I finally did it. I'm taking a slightly different route now though, and somehow I fail to convert it to the original approach. One difference is that I now have my rotation matrices calculated for me by [SPICE](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data.html). When I compare the results, the matrix from $q_\text{sc}$ matches with what SPICE computes, but somehow that for $q_\text{cam}$ is significantly different. I've tripple-checked the quaternion now, and I'm sure the values are correct, so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Another issue is that because of some (I guess historic reasons), the CCD x-axis aligns with the y-axis of the camera reference frame and vice versa. Also, the origin is in the middle of the CCD (which makes sense I guess) and not in the top left corner, so you also need to add 1024px. (also the y values need to be inverted, but that was to be expected).

Comment: Essentially what I do now is convert the target vector from the J2000 reference frame to the spacecraft frame, add the camera-spacecraft vector, which already is in the spacecraft reference frame, and then convert that vector back to the camera frame, and from there compute the pixel coordinates. No need to even use the spacecraft offset vector in J2000. I didn't manage to convert this process into the homogeneous coordinate transformation matrix notation that you use however.